# How to scroll up to a specific date in calendar in appium java

Tags: java, selenium, appium, seetest

I'm scrolling up in list of year in calendar to select specific date like "1998". So how to scroll up to given year and click on that year?

This given code is scrolling up little bit and then scrolling down again two times.
[This image is shows latest calendar ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7H5cY.png)

```
        MobileElement element = (MobileElement) driver
                .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true).instance(0)).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().textContains(\"" + text + "\").instance(0))");
        element.click();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider using [`mobile:shell` command](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/android-shell/) to continuously scroll up until the desired year appears on the screen, example code would be something like:

```
Dimension windowSize = driver.manage().window().getSize();
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
args.put("command", "input");
args.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("swipe", windowSize.width / 2,
        windowSize.height / 2, windowSize.width / 2, windowSize.height));
while (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='1998']")).size() == 0) {
    driver.executeScript("mobile: shell", args);
}
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='1998']")).click();
```

Demo:

[image]

---

Even easier option would be going for [SwipeWhileNotFound](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SwipeWhileNotFound) command available via [SeeTest Appium Extension](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/SeeTest+-+Appium+Extension), it will shorten the code to one-liner:

```
seetest.swipeWhileNotFound("Up", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "xpath=//android.widget.TextView[@text='1998']", 0, 1000, 5, true)
```

Comment: seetest.swipeWhileNotFound("Up", 0, 2000, "NATIVE", "xpath=//android.widget.TextView[@text='1998']", 0, 1000, 5, true)                                        how to use this code.

Comment: first code is also not working, Showing this error Appium server must have relaxed security flag set in order to run any shell commands

Comment: first code is working when you start appium server with this command "appium --relaxed-security" without this command that shows error.

Comment: what to do for year 1997?